# Client side scheduler ? or Server side scheduler?

Tags: websphere, esb, scheduler

In our company we are using ESB and I have a question about scheduling. 
We have lots of information system softwares that exchange data from one to another. 
So which one is a better idea ?

Client applications should create a scheduler to import data ? 
or 
WAS should create a scheduler that import/export data and also trigger a function on the 
client side ?

Thank you by now !

Comment: more info on the client will help

Comment: Polling option from client side?..Publisher and subscriber model will best suite..